# Can two objects of different types with different alingment requirements have the same object representation?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, memory-alignment

The following definition of the object representation is given (3.9/4):

> The *object representation* of an object of type T *is* the sequence of N
>   unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals
>   sizeof(T).

But 3.9.1/1 says:

> A `char`, a `signed char`, and an `unsigned char` occupy the same amount of
>   storage and have *the same alignment requirements* (3.11); that is, they
>   have the same object representation.

It looks like the object representation depends on alignment requirements. But it isn't mentioned in the definition that I cited. That's two object of the same size may have different object representation, do they?

Essentially, I'm asking about the following:
Suppose we have two objects with the same size such that the alignment of one of that objects differs from another. For instance:

```
struct A
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d;
};

A a; //Object 1. alignof(a) = 1
int b; //Object 2. alignof(b) = 4
```

Do these objects have the same object representation?

Comment: If you have any code that could serve as a practical motivating example, that would help.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Unfortunately no, I don't. It's purely theoretical question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that types with manually-specified alignment inside another type would count.

Comment: Are you asking if 2 blobs of memory, of the same size can be represented as 2 different class types ? Or are you asking if the same class may be represented differently with different alignment?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I provided a small example to clarify what I'm asaking.

Comment: Considering that there are only two instances of the phrase "same object representation" in the standard that I can find (the other being corresponding signed and unsigned integer types), I'm rather doubtful that comparing the object representation of two types is a well-defined thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some confusion regarding how alignment works.

You're right that the object representation depends on alignment requirements:

> object representation is the sequence of sizeof(T) objects of type unsigned char

while

> The value representation of an object is the set of bits that hold the value of its type T

If you take for instance the following type:

```
struct S {
    char c;  // 1 byte value
             // 3 bytes padding
    float f; // 4 bytes value
    bool operator==(const S& arg) const { // value-based equality
        return c == arg.c && f == arg.f;
    }
};
assert(sizeof(S) == 8); // object representation
```

the object representation size accounts for 8 bytes but the value representation size accounts only for 5 bytes which determine the object's value with respect to another one. There are alignment requirements which cause the difference and they introduce some padding.

In your example the types have the same size for the object representation and value representation, plus object representation size is equal to the value representation size.

```
struct A
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d;
};

A a; //Object 1. Object representation size = 4, value representation size = 4, alignof(a) = 1
int b; //Object 2. Object representation size = 4, value representation size = 4, alignof(b) = 4
```

What is different here is the alignment required **to store and access the objects**.

On some processors accessing a 4-bytes integer on a non-4-bytes-aligned address yields a fatal error. The `alignof` keyword used in your snippet says exactly this: **you need to allocate an object of type A on a 1-byte-aligned address (i.e. anywhere) since you're going to access subobjects of single bytes as a maximum single read and they're safe to be accessed anywhere, anyway you need to allocate an integer on a 4-bytes aligned address in order to be safe for me to access it**.

§3.11/p1

> Object types have alignment requirements (3.9.1, 3.9.2) which place
>   restrictions on the addresses at which an object of that type may be
>   allocated. An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value
>   representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which
>   a given object can be allocated

That means: you should allocate an integer on a 4-bytes-aligned address, but the bytes necessary from the start of your buffer to the beginning of your object **won't be part of your object**:

```
|0x07|0x08|0x09|0x0A|0x0B|..
     > I can allocate an integer here, on a 4-bytes-aligned address
> Here the buffer starts
      |------------------|
        object rep size == value rep size
```

notice that what would happen if the alignment requirements aren't honored is system-dependent, i.e. on x86 you get a performance slowdown, with SSE you likely will get a crash, on GPU memory spaces you won't be able to recover your program. The standard only specifies what should happen in regard to alignment allocations requests:

> If a request for a specific extended alignment in a specific context
>   is not supported by an implementation, the program is ill-formed.
>   Additionally, a request for runtime allocation of dynamic storage for
>   which the requested alignment cannot be honored shall be treated as an
>   allocation failure.

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of single byte chars, the alignment is irrelevant (one byte boundaries) so the examples cited hold true. However, in more advanced circumstances this is not the case.

As a general rule of thumb, n-byte objects need to be stored on n-byte boundaries. At the processor level, attempting an operation on an incorrectly aligned object results in an exception.

So (without optimization):

```
PTR64     *a;
INT32      b;
INT16      c;
BYTE       d;
```

would be 8+4+2+1 = 15 bytes.
However:

```
BYTE       a;
INT16      b;  // preceded with (1) bytes to 16 bit boundary
INT32      c;  // Preceded with (2) bytes to 32 bit boundary
PTR64     *d;  // preceded with (4) bytes to 64 bit boundary
```

would b 1+(1)+2+(2)+4+(4)+8 = 21 bytes.

Comment: "At the processor level, attempting an operation on an incorrectly aligned object results in an exception." - not on some of the most common processors in use today, including x86 and x86-64.  It *may* result in an error but it doesn't have to.

Comment: Hence "as a general rule of thumb". The exception also applies to simple 8 bit embedded systems which have little or no concept of 16 bit boundaries other than adding a clock cycle if it doesn't align.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course.
Think of **int** and **char[4]** exact same size, different object representation.

You also have **[reinterper_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)** and **[union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)** in the language. These help you look at the same bytes as different object types.

So, working with your example, you could have a union of int, and your struct on the same actual bytes:

```
struct A
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d;
};

union MyUnion
{
   A a;
   int b;
}
```